# Double click instead onclick/oneclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, double-click

Searched other questions for answers, but I think nothing fits my question.
I'm making contact form which popups from the bottom of the page, onclick.
Problem is, that its open on double-click only instead one click as it got to be. Maybe is there in my script is something making conflict with each other.

```
$ ( ".foot" ).click(function() {
            $('.contact-bar').click(function() {
        if($('.foot').hasClass('slide-up')) {
            $('.foot').addClass('slide-down');
            $('.foot').removeClass('slide-up'); 
            $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-angle-up fa-angle-down");
        } else {
            $('.foot').removeClass('slide-down');
            $('.foot').addClass('slide-up'); 
            $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-angle-down fa-angle-up");
        }
    });
});
```

Solved by Rory McCrossan.

Comment: It's because you've put one click handler inside another. Remove the `$('.foot').click(...`

Comment: You can extract second click function out and trigger it like this `$('.contact-bar').trigger('click')`

Comment: Note that a "double-click" is not the same as "two clicks", and I'm pretty sure you're asking about the latter. (All double-clicks do involve clicking twice, but clicking twice doesn't always constitute a "double-click".)

Comment: Rory McCrossan, Thanks. Damn, seems like its time to get sleep.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.contact-bar').click(function() {
    if($('.foot').hasClass('slide-up')) {
        $('.foot').addClass('slide-down');
        $('.foot').removeClass('slide-up'); 
        $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-angle-up fa-angle-down");
    } else {
        $('.foot').removeClass('slide-down');
        $('.foot').addClass('slide-up'); 
        $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-angle-down fa-angle-up");
    }
});

$ ( ".foot" ).click(function() { 
   $('.contact-bar').trigger('click');
})
```